# how to implement afterSave method to a specific controller action only?

Tags: yii

let's say i have model A..then this model A is being used by many controllers...
now I want to implement the afterSave method, only in one of the controllers that uses
model A . e.g in Controller C it calls the save() function, so I want the afterSave to be called in that function only.how is that ?

```
protected function afterSave()
{
    parent::afterSave();
    if($this->isNewRecord)
    {
        echo "hello";
        exit;
    }
}
```

BECAUSE: afterSave() affects all the save() call of all the controllers that uses the Model A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in you `afterSave` function :

```
if (Yii::app()->controller->id!=='yourcontroller')
{
  // do what you want
}
```

If needed, you can also test value of `Yii::app()->controller->action->id`.

**EDIT** : or take a look at *Jelle de Fries* answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why you would need an afterSave() method for this.
In your action you are calling $model->save().
Can't you just do what you have to do after calling this?
like so:

```
public function actionMyAction(){
    $model=new myModel;
    $model->attribute = 5;
    $model->save();
    $model->doLogicAfterSave(); //<-this
    $this->render('myView',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Since it's only for 1 controller.